# Renaming Google Sheets File Automatically From A Cell

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script

I'm a complete novice to script, so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm trying to run a script so that when a new sheet is made of a specific set of sheets I use for my clients, that new copy renames itself upon the input of a specific cell (C13) where my clients will enter their name.

I should add I was using the following code that i grabbed from a similar question on here:

```js
function onOpen() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var C13 = ss.getRange("C13").getValue(); 
  var name = C13; 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("name"); 
}
```

But this only worked for when the sheet opened, and obviously with nothing in C13 this isn't useful

Thank you

Comment: I'd probably consider using insert Spreadsheet.insertSheet() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Integer,Object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish that the sheet gets renamed when a specific range gets edited than you can use `onEdit()` trigger.

The code below will replace the sheet's name with C13 cell's value if you change it.

```js
function onEdit(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var name = ss.getRange("C13").getValue(); 
  
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C13' && name!= '') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the onEdit function and that gave me exactly what I needed

Comment: I would be grateful if you mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: @Rocky  It returns **Error 404: Page not found**

Comment: @Rocky Corrected link: [rename multiple sheets](https://talentnett.com/how-to-get-sheets-name-and-rename-them-using-google-script/)

Comment: Just in case if you want to rename multiple sheets to be renamed [How to get sheets name and rename them using Google Script](https://talentnett.com/how-to-get-sheets-name-and-rename-them-using-google-script/) thanks @NikitaSkrebets